# Page break issues in Bootstrap 4 and SimpleQR code in blade template?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, printing, laravel-blade

I am trying to generate a batch of QR codes via the SimpleQR code generator in Laravel blade template on the fly for printing. But it breaks the QR code when a page break occurs. I tried using the break-inside property to avoid, but it didn't solve the issue. Also, one of the solutions I found, I have to set the display property to block because it uses flex box. However, it didn't work as on the parent div surrounding the SVG.
The current state of my code is:

```
@media print{
    div{
        break-inside: avoid !important;
    }

}

</style>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center" style="margin: 2em">
            <div class="btn btn-info add-new" id="printbtn" onclick="printDiv()" value="Print QR"> Print</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            @foreach ($items as $item)
                <div class="col" id="print1" >
                        <div class="visible-print text-center" style="padding: 1em">
                            {!! QrCode::size($height)->generate(url('/product/show/' . $item->id)) !!}
                            <p><small>{{ $item->material_id }}</small></p>
                        </div>
                </div>
             @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a `<figure>` element instead of using a `<div>`. And then targeting the figure element

> @media print {
>       figure {
>         break-inside: avoid;
>     
>       }
>     }

The making the following changes in your HTML part

> ```
>   <div class="col" id="print1" >
>                         <figure class="visible-print text-center" style="padding: 1em">
>                             {!! QrCode::size($height)->generate(url('/product/show/' . $item->id)) !!}
>                             <p><small>{{ $item->material_id }}</small></p>
>                         </figure>
>                     </div>
> ```